# listings font in pdflatex

Tags: listings, pdftex

I'm using `\ttfamily` but it renders listing with the Times New Roman. What am I doing wrong? I'm getting a warning message:

> Font shape `T2A/fi4/bx/n' undefined(Font) using`T2A/fi4/m/n' instead on input line 322. Font shape `T2A/fi4/bx/n' undefined(Font) using`T2A/fi4/m/n' instead`.

```tex
\lstset{
    commentstyle = \color{gray},
    extendedchars=\true,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    columns=fixed,
    inputencoding=utf8x,
    language = php,
    keepspaces=true,
    keywordstyle = \bfseries,
    morekeywords={function, return, new}
}
```

Comment: Seems like it’s a `fontenc` problem … Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: The Inconsolata font is not available in the T2A encoding for Russian (and other languages using the cyrillic script). As far as I can tell, the only available monospaced font is the cyrillic version of `cmtt`.

Comment: Please consider accepting your own answer, so that your question be removed from the "unanswered" pile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @egreg said

> The Inconsolata font is not available in the T2A encoding for Russian (and other languages using the cyrillic script). As far as I can tell, the only available monospaced font is the cyrillic version of cmtt.

So I wrote

```tex
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}
```

And now it works fine.